# Show group opener on Notebook startup

Tags: notebooks, cells

When I re-open a previously saved notebook in which a group of cells is expanded, the group opener sign does not appear. See, for example

[image]

However when I collapse using the right-side group tracks and re-expand it **using the opener button**, it appears

[image]

Is it possible to make it appear when I open the notebook by default? Is this a bug? I know about `ShowGroupOpener`, but not sure how to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: Has this been confirmed as a bug? If not, the bugs tag should not be used. Have you contacted WRI to report this behavior as a bug? If so, perhaps they may provide a workaround. I’ll remove the bugs tag until this is confirmed as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This simple command will give you GroupOpeners in front of your segments:

`SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowGroupOpener -> True];`